# Unable to click on a button using PyWinAuto

Tags: pywinauto

Hi I am new to Pywinauto tool and i am using Microsoft Accessibility Insights to inspect an element.I Am trying to click on a particular button inside my application as shown in the picture. i have tried with many solution and it is not working for me. Can someone help me to resolve this issue. I want to click on the "Create Process" button present in the application. please find the screenshot for reference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ3Kl.png)

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().start("C:/Program Files (x86)/DRSL/TruBot Designer/WFSetupFiles/TrubotDesigner.exe")

time.sleep(10)

win = app.window(title='Datamatics TruBot Designer - 4.6.0')

win.print_control_identifiers()

win.child_window(best_match='Create Process').Click()

object Identifier
Control Identifiers:

HwndWrapper[TrubotDesigner.exe;;9f80079c-7325-495f-a163-862cd8146ab6] - 'Datamatics TruBot Designer - 4.6.0'    (L-8, T-8, R1374, B736)
['HwndWrapper[TrubotDesigner.exe;;9f80079c-7325-495f-a163-862cd8146ab6]', 'Datamatics TruBot Designer - 4.6.0HwndWrapper[TrubotDesigner.exe;;9f80079c-7325-495f-a163-862cd8146ab6]', 'Datamatics TruBot Designer - 4.6.0']
child_window(title="Datamatics TruBot Designer - 4.6.0", class_name="HwndWrapper[TrubotDesigner.exe;;9f80079c-7325-495f-a163-862cd8146ab6]")
```

error :

```
raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
```

Comment: Have you read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)? Also it's good practice to show your efforts and provide some code you've tried and detailed error message. StackOverflow is not for writing the whole code for you.

Comment: I have tried the following code to interact with application. However i am stuck with the clicking of the particular button that i have shown in image.

Comment: It looks like WPF application. You must use `Application(backend="uia")`. That's why I suggested to read the Getting Started Guide which starts from backend selection as a basic thing!

Comment: Also `win.wait('ready', timeout=10)` before `win.print_control_identifiers()` is more flexible.